# how to type() the value of cy.readFile()

Tags: types, cypress, readfile, writefile

sorry I am new to cypress

and I just want to type a number, it will be increased when tester runs a test

first attempt - 1
second attempt - 2 .. and so on

I wrote this code

```
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/message.txt', '1')
```

```
cy.get('[data-cy="firstname-input').type(`First ${cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/message.txt')}`)
```

I tried
make it Json and JSON.stringify()

how can I access the contents of readFile?

but it gives me this:

First [object Object]

I tried to use localStorage at first but cypress deletes all the values when it starts
and I found that I need to use package to solve that so now I just want to use write/read file

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Create a `message.json` file in the fixtures folder with the content:

```json
{
  "count": 0
}
```

In your test:

```js
    cy.fixture("message.json").then((message) => {

      // we now have access to the json file, and use it for cypress commands
      cy.get('[data-cy="firstname-input').type(`First ${message.count}`);

      // we can update the json file
      cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/message.json", {
        count: message.count + 1,
      });
    });
```

- `cy.fixture()` will look in your fixtures folder for a file called `message.json`
- You can access the value of the current count with `message.count`
- Inside the `.then()` block you can use this value for different commands
- You use the `cy.writeFile()` to overwrite this same fixture file with the new value